# How do I restore a theme in Outlook 2003?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, themes, microsoft-outlook-2003

Is there a way to restore a theme in Outlook 2003?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an Outlook point of view, you could check if the application's shortcut
hasn't been marked to run Outlook in XP's compatibility mode.
You could also check if the issue isn't being caused by a 3rd party addin by
starting Outlook in Safe Mode;

Start-> Run; outlook.exe /safe